# How to delete the profile AD attribute using dsmod or similar?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, active-directory

As part of a user management batch script, I need to delete the profile value from an AD User object.

The syntax I'm using is as follows:

```
dsquery user -name TEST | dsmod user -profile ""
```

It appears to work (no errors), however, upon querying the object again, the old profile value still remains.

If I were to add a space, for eg:

```
dsquery user -name TEST | dsmod user -profile " "
```

Then it does update the profile value, but now the profile value is now a space, which is not what I want - I'd like the value to be completely empty.

This appears to be a bug, as the same syntax works with other parameters, eg **-loscr ""** will clear the value of the logon script attribute.

Any workarounds / insights into this issue are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct. I tried it with some test accounts, and it worked as you were hoping.

Are you, by chance, using Server 2003? If so, [Microsoft article KB824678](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/824678) may apply to you.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick!

I was actually on Windows XP, so I had to extract the contents of the hotfix and replaced the exes in the System32 folder, and it worked just great. The profile value is getting updated correctly now.